# DotNetOpenAuth OpenID provider not accepting requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth, openid-provider

I've done my best to duplicate the DotNetOpenAuth OpenID provider sample in a new project, mostly to learn how to use it. I use the DotNetOpenAuth OpenID RP example to test. When I run both samples (provider and rp), and point the rp to the provider's url, everything goes correctly.

But after hours of frustration, I have done my best to copy the provider sample into my project, but I still cannot get the rp sample to recognize my provider.

I have turned on every kind of log that I can for DotNetOpenAuth, but I dont get any helpful information. Here is what I do get: http://pastebin.com/k4XYnu8q

Since I cannot nail down a solid reason for why, I thought it would be helpful to provide the **entire** project. Obviously, I know some people wont download an archived file, so I uploaded the project to github. It can be accessed [here](https://github.com/adam8797/Iris).

I have done some asking on the DotNetOpenAuth Jabbr channel, but I was just advised to post here.

So, here is what I am asking.

- Does anyone have any ideas on why this wont work? All my code is available on the github page. I have been working on this for days, so I am willing to take almost any solution.

  **OR**
- Does anyone know of a good tutorial so that I could rework this project the right way?

**Edit**

I know full well that this question is not very specific. And I would happily specify it, but I can't. I am at a total loss for what is causing this, so therefore I am at a total loss for what to ask. That is why this question is slightly more open ended then the usual question.

**Edit 2**

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1849799/643930) answer, but that is not the problem.

**Edit 3** I thought It may be helpful to add that I am using DNOA 5.0, but I can switch it back to 4.x. Also, as you can see I opened a bounty on this question. I made the value higher as I expect the person who answers will have to dig through the project on github, [referenced here](https://github.com/adam8797/Iris)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just missed you in the JabbR room. Left a message for you.

For starters I would not use DNOA 5.0 as it's currently in 'alpha'. Please try recreate using the version you can get from the 'stable' nuget feed.

David

Answer (score 0):

DotNetOpenAuth uses **XRDS** to discover OP Endpoint URL. In OpenIdProviderMvc sample project there is a file named "xrsd.aspx", Copy that file into your project and everything will work correctly.
For more information about OpenID and XRDS go to this Address:
http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#discovery